# GCP: Unable to connect to cloud TPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tpu

I started an instance with TPU by following [this quick start tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/quickstart) using `ctpu up` command and I was able to run MNIST tutorial successfully. I logged out of cloud shell and logged into my vm connected to TPU using SSH console as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance), when I run MNIST tutorial again I'm getting

```
RuntimeError: Cannot find any TPU cores in the system. Please double check Tensorflow master address and TPU worker(s).
```

When I run `ctpu ls`, I get

```
#       Flock Name      Status
0:      my-tpu(*)  running
```

`ctpu status` command gives

```
Your cluster is running!
Compute Engine VM:  RUNNING
Cloud TPU:          RUNNING
```

Am I missing something basic here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctpu` passes this name to the Compute Engine VM as an environment variable (`TPU_NAME`), but `gcloud` doesn't.

Specify your TPU explicitly: use `--tpu=my-tpu` instead of `--tpu=$TPU_NAME`